# regex styleguide with plaintext

Tags: regex, tokenize

I'm trying to start with tokenize, since I want to write my own scripting-language based on C#.

So for now, I'm just playing a bit round and I'm learning regex a bit deeper. So, I'm pretty new to regex.

For example, I want to match

```
foreach(str x:test.GetItems())
```

and get the groupvalues `str`, `x`, `test.GetItems()`

my regex is:

```
foreach\s*\((\s*([A-Za-z0-9]+)\s+([A-Za-z0-9]+))\s*\:\s*(.+)\)
```

and this works so far.

so my questions are:

- is it good practice to have something like hardcoded character-sequences, e.g. `foreach` in my regex? If not, **what would you prefer me to do**?
- for the `:` in my syntax, I can write in regex `:` or also `\:`. RegExr.com allows both and matches both (but displays them in other colors. nevertheless, it writes `Matches a ":" character (char code 58).`) **Should I escape the character, or shouldn't I?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it good practice to have something like hard-coded character-sequences [...] in my regex?

You need to match a literal string, (`foreach`, `using` or even `potato`) then write it as is. There is absolutely no reason why you would escape/split/anythingelse with it.

> for the `:` in my syntax, I can write in regex `:` or also `\:`. [...] Should I escape the character, or shouldn't I?

Since `:` doesn't have any special meaning, you don't have to escape it. Furthermore, you *shouldn't* escape it, because some regex engine might raise a syntax error.

The color mismatch may be due to improper parsing like this screenshot suggest: [image]

`c` should be purple or all other should be black (except `\s`)